# Issues using Spring Social Quickstart example

Tags: facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to use the Spring Social Quickstart app from the Github repo, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples. I updated the versions in build.gradle and ran the app.

A simple page was display with a button, "Sign in with Facebook". If I'm not already signed in with Facebook, I get an FB error page telling me to sign in (seems a bit contradictory!). If I sign-in and run the app, I get an error dialog saying:

```
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
whitelisted in the app's Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and 
Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth 
Redirect URIs.
```

When I click on the "Okay" button, another error message pops up saying it "Can't Load URL" (there's more to it, but I figure the first error is the key one). This error keeps popping up every time I hit the "Okay" button.

As far as I know, everything on the Facebook app is configured correctly, but not 100% sure.

One other thing, when the "Sign in ..." button is pushed, the URL opened shows that it's trying to connect using v2.5 of the FB API. Don't know where this is being set, but it is 3 versions behind.

Going through the Spring docs as well, but there are a lot of moving pieces to work through. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I discovered after looking more closely at the URL when the error comes up that I had the redirect URL incorrect. Once I corrected that, I was able to login and get the extra permission added.

I'd still like to know about where the version for the API is set.